# How to get DAC record from Note Table

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone have a code snippet on how to go from RefNoteId => DAC when I dont know what dac type the note is attached to?

I have made it this far (row.RefNoteID is what I am starting from)

```
        Note note = PXSelect<Note, Where<Note.noteID, Equal<Required<Note.noteID>>>>.Select(this, row.RefNoteID);
        Type recordType = Type.GetType(note.EntityType);
        PXCache recordCache = Caches[recordType];
```

How can I now do a PXSelect<recordType, Where<recodType.noteID, Equal<Required<recordType.noteID>>>>.Select(GRAPH) ? The recordType could be any DAC in the system that has a noteID.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code works for me and it is based on the way Acumatica gets the record inside the `PXRefNoteSelectorAttribute.PrimaryRow_RowPersisted`.

The problem with this approach is that this will work for Header entities like SOOrder, INRegister, SOInvoice, SOShipment, and others. But for "detail" entities like SOLine, INTran, and others this approach will work only if that corresponding record has some Note related to Text/File. Acumatica is adding records corresponding to their NoteID into the Note table only if that detail records have some Note/Text. My best guess is that this is done in order to avoid over-spamming the Note table.

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Compilation;

namespace SearchByNoteID
{
    // Acuminator disable once PX1016 ExtensionDoesNotDeclareIsActiveMethod extension should be constantly active
    public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public PXAction<SOOrder> searchByNoteID;

        [PXUIField(DisplayName ="Search by Note ID")]
        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        public virtual IEnumerable SearchByNoteID(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            var order = adapter.Get<SOOrder>().FirstOrDefault();
            if(order!=null)
            {
                //
                //...
                //
                Guid? noteID = GetNoteID();
                object record = GetRecordByNoteID(noteID);
                //
                //... do whatever you want with the record
                //
            }
            return adapter.Get();
        }
        protected object GetRecordByNoteID(Guid? noteID)
        {
            var type = GetEntityType(this.Base, noteID);
            if(type==null) return null;
            object entityRow = new EntityHelper(this.Base).GetEntityRow(type, noteID);
            return entityRow;
        }
        protected Type GetEntityType(PXGraph graph, Guid? noteID)
        {
            if (noteID == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            Note note = PXSelectBase<Note, PXSelect<Note, Where<Note.noteID, Equal<Required<Note.noteID>>>>.Config>.SelectWindowed(graph, 0, 1, new object[]
            {
                noteID
            });
            if (note == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(note.EntityType))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return PXBuildManager.GetType(note.EntityType, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Samvel! Luckily I can force a note creation for any record that goes through this process.